# how we can i use google translator api in my website

Tags: google-translate

Well I want to use Google api translator in my website and when I am putting this api code in my html page it's working fine.

----------------------------------**google translator code :**-----------------------------

```
<div id="google_translate_element" ></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
function googleTranslateElementInit() {
  new google.translate.TranslateElement({
    pageLanguage: 'en'
  }, 'google_translate_element');
}

</script><script src="http://translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>
```

I want to put the code in  when I am putting this code in iframe then it shows everything.

But while changing the language it changes the language of elements in the iframe it doesn't affect outside the iframe.

Comment: Is there any thing to do to limit the translate languages.Because I want to translate my site with 3 language only

Answer (score 2):

I guess this is why the **iframe** tag is used to include an external document into an existing one.

Google Translator will translate the content of the *iframe* only, since it has no clue about the *container document*.

Please see also:

http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=467248